# Eclipse RCP app keeps unbundling resources into org.eclipse.osgi configuration folder

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I just noticed that one of our e4 RCP application keeps unbundling resources (eg, jars and icons) into a sub-folder in the `configuration/org.eclipse.osgi`, at **every single run of the application**. Consequently, the configuration folder quickly grows out of control.

Any idea what could be causing that?

Edit: it appears the issue might be specific to Windows. I cannot replicate on Ubuntu (GTK) or MacOS. All platforms are 64-bit ones.

Comment: It is normal for things to be unpacked in to this location but the size should stay under control.

Answer (score 0):

The issue came from the bundles.info configuration file in org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/. For deployment reasons, we had removed our bundle (the main app bundle) from there. While the OSGi of Eclipse Luna seemed to handle this just fine, unpacking the resources and assets, it seems that Mars and above do not like that, and Equinox attempted to unpack resources at every single run.